# getting method not found exception while consuming rabbitmq message

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

Have created on consumer class to consume message from rabbitMQ GUI.

but when i am publishing any message from rabbitMQ GUI its giving error class not found. and continuously error is printing on console.

may be problem is rabbitGUI sending message in from of byte, and i am trying to receive it on string.

I wanted to call the particular method based on message body.

```java
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues =  {"#{addNeRangeQueue.name}"})
public class consumerController {

    @RabbitHandler
    public void receive(String message) {
        System.out.println("rabbit mq listener receive : "+message);
    }
}
   
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConsumerConfig {
 
    //properties value configuration i have removed here.
    @Bean
    public Queue addNeRangeQueue() {
        return new Queue(queueName,false);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange getTopicEchangeName() {
        return new TopicExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindaddNeRange(TopicExchange getTopicEchangeName, Queue addNeRangeQueue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(addNeRangeQueue).to(getTopicEchangeName).with(routingkey);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
2020-09-08 00:19:10.378  WARN 9456 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
    
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1705) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1595) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1489) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1433) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:970) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:916) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1291) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1197) [spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
    Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: No method found for class [B
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:151) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getMethodFor(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:270) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.getMethodFor(HandlerAdapter.java:84) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:146) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:133) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1591) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When publishing from the UI, you have to add a `content_type` property so the message converter knows what to convert the `byte[]` message body to.

With method-level `@RabbitListener`, the converter can infer the type from the method parameter - this is not possible with the class level annotation because we need to do the conversion first to determine which method to call.

For a simple String with the default `SimpleMessageConverter`:

[image]

When using JSON (and the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`):

[image]

Comment: thanks, yes i use Jackson2JsonMessageConverter to convert message from rabbitMQ GUI than it worked.